# What is the effect of the Gell-Mann matrices on color antiparticles?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, quantum-chromodynamics, group-representations, color-charge

I'm studying QCD and I can't understand how exactly are defined the color antiparticles. Indeed, we have the particle color triplet $(r,g,b)$. With the usual SU(3) algebra, we define the 8 Gell-Mann matrices. Now, we know exactly the effect of the Gell-Mann matrices on any quark of color r, g, or b.

However, what is the effect of $\lambda_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &0 \\ 
 1&  0& 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ on an antiquark $\overline{r}$, for example ? I know in SU(2) it was convenient because we could express antiparticle doublet simply by $(-\overline{d},\overline{u})$, and thus the effect of the Pauli matrices is directly defined.

Another related question is, how do you find the gluon wavefunction corresponding to the Gell-Mann matrices ? It's pretty straightforward for most of them by color charge conservation, except $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_8$ for which in my book there is given respectively $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(r\overline{r}-g\overline{g})$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(r\overline{r}+g\overline{g}-2b\overline{b})$, and I can't figure out why we choose those exactly and not other ones in the octet. Is this an arbitrary choice and we could have choosen $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(r\overline{r}-b\overline{b})$ for $\lambda_3$, for instance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a triplet $q\equiv (r,g,b)$, action of a Gell-Mann matrix is multiplication from the left, so $\lambda_i q$. For an antitriplet, $\bar{q}$, multiplication of the transpose on the right, $\bar{q}^T \lambda_i$. So an anti-red would be mapped to an anti-green by $\lambda_1$.

The 2-dim Cartan subalgebra of SU(3) may be spanned by any linear combination of 
$\lambda_3, \lambda_8$. So, of course, the combination you are proposing, $(\lambda_3+\sqrt{3}\lambda_8)/2$, and $\lambda_8$ are a perfectly acceptable alternate set, mathematically. In an alternative physical world, in which the up quark were closer in mass to the strange quark than to the down quark, of course *that* would be the combination to pick.